# MB issue of scroll bar

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a display having lots of div in it also having filter option at the menu bar. When i resize the window on IE then all the div adjust them self according to the size but on chrome when i resize the window then the scroll bar adjust its height to the height of the filter div which is not visible(it will be visible if we click on the filter). which result to have more spaces below the body because the height of the filter div is larger then the resized window. It is happening on both chrome and Firefox but it is working fine on IE

can anyone help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please edit your question to include your code. - It sounds like you're CSS to setup just for IE, all the web browser behave a bit differently and some have different rules. I suggest trying a CSS reset to ensure that you have a uniform css setup across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Give code examples if you want better help from this community. But I think that if it works in IE, but not in the other browsers, you may have to add `-webkit-` and `-moz-` to some of your CSS lines.